# remove demarcation from text image - image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Hi I need to write a program that remove demarcation from gray scale image(image with text in it)
i read about thresholding and blurring but still i dont see how can i do it.

my image is an image of a hebrew text like that:

[image: input]
and i need to remove the demarcation(assuming that the demarcation is the smallest element in the image) the output need to be something like that

[image: output]
I want to write the code in python using opencv, what topics do i need to learn to be able to do that, and how?

thank you.

Edit:
I can use only cv2 functions

Answer (score 3):

The symbols you want to remove are significantly smaller than all other shapes, you can use that to determine witch ones to remove.

First use [threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) to convert the image to binary. Next, you can use [findContours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) to detect the shapes and then [contourArea](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-area) to determine if the shape is larger than a threshold.

Finally you can can create a mask to remove the unwanted shapes, draw the larger symbols on a new image or draw the smaller symbols in white over the original symbols in the original image - making them disappear. I used that last technique in the code below.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('1MioS.png',0)
# convert to binary. Inverted, so you get white symbols on black background
_ , thres = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find contours in the thresholded image (this gives all symbols)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thres, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# loop through the contours, if the size of the contour is below a threshold, 
# draw a white shape over it in the input image
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 250:
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255),-1)
# display result
cv2.imshow('res', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Update**

To find the largest contour, you can loop through them and keep track of the largest value:

```
maxArea = 0
for cnt in contours:
    currArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if currArea > maxArea:
        maxArea = currArea
print(maxArea)
```

I also whipped up a little more complex version, that creates a sorted list of the indexes and sizes of the contours. Then it looks for the largest relative difference in size of all contours, so you know which contours are 'small' and 'large'.  I do not know if this works for all letters / fonts.

```
# create a list of the indexes of the contours and their sizes
contour_sizes = []
for index,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    contour_sizes.append([index,cv2.contourArea(cnt)])

# sort the list based on the contour size. 
# this changes the order of the elements in the list
contour_sizes.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])

# loop through the list and determine the largest relative distance
indexOfMaxDifference = 0
currentMaxDifference = 0
for i in range(1,len(contour_sizes)):
    sizeDifference = contour_sizes[i][1] / contour_sizes[i-1][1] 
    if sizeDifference > currentMaxDifference:
        currentMaxDifference = sizeDifference
        indexOfMaxDifference = i

# loop through the list again, ending (or starting) at the indexOfMaxDifference, to draw the contour
for i in range(0, indexOfMaxDifference):
    cv2.drawContours(img,contours,contour_sizes[i][0]     ,(255),-1)
```

To get the background color you can do use `minMaxLoc`. This returns the lowest color value and it's position of an image (also the max value, but you don't need that). If you apply it to the thresholded image - where the background is black -, it will return the location of a background pixel (big odds it will be (0,0) ). You can then look up this pixel in the original color image.

```
# get the location of a pixel with background color
min_val, _, min_loc, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(thres)
# load color image
img_color = cv2.imread('1MioS.png')
# get bgr values of background
b,g,r = img_color[min_loc]
# convert from numpy object
background_color = (int(b),int(g),int(r))
```

and then to draw the contours

```
cv2.drawContours(img_color,contours,contour_sizes[i][0],background_color,-1)
```

and of course

```
cv2.imshow('res', img_color)
```

Comment: thank you so much, thats the answer i was looking for. can i ask if my background isnt just white, how can i know to what to assign in the pixels that i want to erase? and how can i get the biggest contour size?

Comment: i tried to use your code on an image with smaller text and thats erased most of the text, im thinking on taking the biggest contour size and divide that by some number(lets assume 1000) and then erase all the smaller contours, how can i get the biggest contour

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem for *template matching* since you have what looks like a known font and can easily understand what the characters and/or demarcations are. Check out https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Admittedly, the tutorial talks about finding the match; modification is up to you. In that case, you know the exact shape of the template itself, so using that information along with the location of the match, just overwrite the image data with the appropriate background color (based on the examples above, 255).

Comment: What if i need to use only cv2 functions?

Comment: The above tutorial describes using exactly that to solve the problem and only relies on `matplotlib` for plotting the results neatly. You could use `cv2.imshow()` as well, so look up the documentation for that. Also note that `cv2` depends on `numpy`, so its usage would be fair-game to that constraint.

Comment: Thanks, its very interesting. But cant i do that operation only with opening closing blurring and thresholding? Thats the main goal of this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by removing all the small clusters.

I found a Python solution (using OpenCV) [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/194566/removing-noise-using-connected-components/).

For supporting smaller fonts, I added the following heuristic:
"The largest size of the demarcation cluster is 1/500 of the largest letter cluster".
The heuristic can be refined, by statistical analysts (or improved by other heuristics, such as demarcation locations relative to the letters).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

I = cv2.imread('Goodluck.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

J = 255 - I  # Invert I
img = cv2.threshold(J, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] # Convert to binary

# https://answers.opencv.org/question/194566/removing-noise-using-connected-components/
nlabel,labels,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, connectivity=8)

labels_small = []
areas_small = []

# Find largest cluster:
max_size = np.max(stats[:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
thresh_size = max_size / 500  # Set the threshold to maximum cluster size divided by 500.

for i in range(1, nlabel):
    if stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < thresh_size:
        labels_small.append(i)
        areas_small.append(stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])

    mask = np.ones_like(labels, dtype=np.uint8)

for i in labels_small:
    I[labels == i] = 255

cv2.imshow('I', I)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

Here is a MATLAB code sample (kept threshold = 200):

```matlab
clear

I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(imread('בהצלחה.png')));

figure;imshow(I);

J = ~I;

%Clustering
CC  = bwconncomp(J);

%Cover all small clusters with zewros.
for i = 1:CC.NumObjects
    C = CC.PixelIdxList{i}; %Cluster coordinates.

    %Fill small clusters with zeros.
    if numel(C) < 200
        J(C) = 0;
    end    
end

J = ~J;

figure;imshow(J);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont understand that code at all. What the idea behind that? And how can i do that not just for this specific image, but to every grayscale image?

Comment: It's simple: find all the clusters, check the size (number of pixels) of each cluster, and cover the cluster  if size is less than 200 pixels. `J = ~I` is just inversion (turn black to white, and white to black).

Comment: Why less than 200 pixels, whats about a very small text?

Comment: I added the following heuristic: "The largest size of the demarcation cluster is 1/500 of the largest letter cluster". **בהצלחה** (Good luck).